# Delete git commit completely in local and remote repo shared by other hundred developers

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-commit

Here is the situation:

> A newbie developer has commited and pushed sensible credentials to remote dev branch, which is strictly forbidden
>
> This forbidden commit then got merged into the master branch together with other hundred commits afterwards
>
> The forbidden commit has been pulled by other hundred developers into their local repos

Question: How to get rid of this forbidden commit completely with as less "pain" as possible?

Comment: You can excise the file from your published history, but what other people do with what they already have is up to them.  @shambalambala's got [the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43919083/1290731) for what I see here.

Answer (score 1):

If other people have pulled the sensitive credentials from the repository, **there is no way you can force them to delete it**.

Of course, you could amend the commit and push with the `--force` option to overwrite the remote data. But users would get an error when they try to pull, because you would have *re-written history*.

The *only* viable option for you at this point is to **disable the credentials that have been leaked**.

Render those credentials useless, ensure they cannot be used anymore to use whichever service they give access to.

Generate new credentials, and don't put them in the git repository this time.

Answer (score 0):

Well... pain? There's gonna be some because everyone is already working on top of a revision (or revisions) that you want to get rid of, right? But you are all professionals and know how to use git so, if you send a mail telling people something like `hit guys and gals. Sorry to bother. We need to remove some revisions from our X branch and so people who are already on top of it will have to move their changes to the new branch once we push--force it. Will let you know when this happens so you can move your changes over`, developers should be able to understand that they will have to cherry-pick or *rebase--onto* the changes to the new branch so that they don't bring over the revisions that you are trying to get rid of.

This is **my** personal opinion: this is not the best thing to happen, but it happens every so often so it's business-as-usual, if you ask me. Moving over changes this way is *extremely* easy with git.

Comment: by the way, I just tackeld the "what will happen with the other developers" part. Talking about what should happen with the branch to clean it up:
- reset --hard to the last revision you definitely want to keep from the branch before the messed up revisions start. Then start cherry-picking the other revisions you want to keep that are _after_ the revisions you want to get rid of. In the end you should be able to get a branch that is "cleaned up". push --force it to the remote branch and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If the file has been recently committed that file, or if that file has changed in just one or two commits, then I'd suggest you use `rebase` or `cherrypick` to remove that particular commit.

Otherwise, you'd have to rewrite the entire history.

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f <path_to_file>' HEAD
```

When you are satisfied with the changes and have duly ensured that everything seems fine, you need to update all remote branches -

```
git push origin --force --all
```

*Note:- It's a complex operation, and you must be aware of what are you doing. First try doing it on a demo repository to see how it works. You also need to let other developers know about it, such that they don't make any change in the mean time.*